# Databricks SQL Error: Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm getting the error:

> TableName is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate
> function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you
> don't care which value you get.;

When I execute the following code in Databricks SQL

```
SELECT 
ts_originationopportunity,
concat_ws(distinctreferrals.referralcompanycontact,'; ')  AS referralcompanycontacts
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
     ts_originationopportunity,
     IFNULL(ts_referralcontactname + ' at ','') + ts_referralcompanyname AS referralcompanycontact
     FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource) distinctreferrals
GROUP BY ts_originationopportunity
```

I had already received assistance with a similar question by @Tim Biegeleisen, however when  applied the suggested code from the previous question I get no results from 'referralcompanycontact'

```
SELECT 
ts_originationopportunity,
array_join(collect_set(distinctreferrals.referralcompanycontact),'; ')  AS referralcompanycontacts
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
     ts_originationopportunity,
     IFNULL(ts_referralcontactname + ' at ','') + ts_referralcompanyname AS referralcompanycontact
     FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource) distinctreferrals
GROUP BY ts_originationopportunity
```

Any thoughts?

I have now tried the following:

```
SELECT
  ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity
 ,CONCAT_WS(ts_referralsource.ts_referralcontactname, ' at ', ts_referralsource.ts_referralcompanyname), ';') AS referralcompanycontact
FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource
GROUP BY ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity
```

But getting the error:

```
== SQL ==
SELECT
  ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity
 ,CONCAT_WS(ts_referralsource.ts_referralcontactname, ' at ', ts_referralsource.ts_referralcompanyname), ';') AS referralcompanycontact
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

ok, I almost figured it out.

The following will get me my results without the groupby

```
SELECT
 ts_originationopportunity
 ,CONCAT(ts_referralcontactname, ' at ', ts_referralcompanyname) AS referralcompanycontact
FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource
-- GROUP BY ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity
```

However, with the groupby I the following error:

```
'spark_catalog.baseorigination.ts_referralsource.ts_referralcontactname' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the first thing in ( ) like the error suggested?

Comment: Hi @easleyfixed, thanks for reaching out. Yes, in my second example, I tried wrapping the first thing in () but I got no results from 'referralcompanycontact'

Comment: Hi Community, I think my last update should be easier to find a solution for..

Comment: There are enough differences from MySQL to Bricks for me to scratch my head on this one.   Like I don't know about CONCAT_WS but normal CONCAT can combine things where you have a dynamic column name needing to be selected via user input.

Comment: ok, @easleyfixed, you have a good point. I just included normal CONCAT, and I appear to get results, see updated question. However,  I keep on getting the error with GROUPBY. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh sweet it helped :) Hmm okay let me see about that GROUP by...

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY (ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity) . with the ( )?
However its sort of claiming that it doesn't exist ..  but it could be a Bricks thing .. but the way that CONCAT looks is strange to me the formatting at least ...

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out WHY you are using CONCAT in the first place.  Is one of the things going into this statement USER SUPPLIED ?  Cause if it isn't, why not just code in directly without combinding them, unless this is all so you can use the AS command, but since you know the column name (if its not user supplied) you dont need to do that, do you ?

Comment: SELECT
 ts_originationopportunity,
ts_referralcontactname
FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource
GROUP BY ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity   .

Note that use of "referralcompanycontact" won't exist but unless you really need that for something else .. its more of a decoration.

Comment: As the error states in SQL in general you can't select all values in a column while using group by since group by is an aggregate identifier. For example : ```select colA, colB from table group by colA;``` won't work cause colB can't be agregate nor it is specified in the group by. So you either need to change the group by to ```group by colA, colB``` or use a function for agregation like ```select colA, first(colB) from table group by colA```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error when I tried to use group by in a similar manner. The following is a sample table on which I have tried to use similar query:

[image]

- When I tried the following query (similar to yours), I got the same error:

```
SELECT a,CONCAT(b, ' at ', c) AS new FROM demo GROUP BY a
```

[image]

- This is because you are not aggregating the columns that you are selecting i.e., `b and c` in the above query (ts_referralcontactname and ts_referralcompanyname in your case).
- So as suggested in the error message, you have to apply an appropriate aggregate function. I have used `first` in my case and got the desired result.

```
SELECT a,CONCAT(first(b), ' at ', first(c)) AS new FROM demo GROUP BY a
```

[image]

- Now, since you are getting desired result even without group by, change your query as shown below:

```
SELECT
 ts_originationopportunity
 ,CONCAT(first(ts_referralcontactname), ' at ', first(ts_referralcompanyname)) AS referralcompanycontact
FROM baseorigination.ts_referralsource GROUP BY ts_referralsource.ts_originationopportunity
```